# python3: read two text files and print each file in vertical split so easy to log for comparing

Tags: python-3.x

I am thinking is it possible to achieve the below in python3

I have two text files

File 1

```
===========================================================================
0100 - Request Message    RSC Transaction ID  :N80L2G
===========================================================================
DE-000  004 0100
DE-002  16  0078700081608
```

File 2

```
===========================================================================
0100 - Request Message    RSC Transaction ID  :N80L2L
===========================================================================
DE-000  004 0100
DE-002  16  000006776609
```

I want to read the file and print or create a new file like html vertical page split ,in column file 1 content and in the next file2 content.

is that something achievable ,any ideas

I found this , but the issue here its not printing  all the files i.e if one file 
has more number of lines it is not iterating , for example if file2 has more lines it stops at the point where file1 lines end

```
with open(file1) as f1:
    with open(file2) as f2:
        for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
            # print("{0}\t{1}".format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
            print('{:<100} {}'.format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
```

Solution

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

if file_len(file1) >= file_len(file2):

    with open(file1,'r') as f1,open(file2,'r') as f2:
        for i in f1.readlines():
            print('{:<100} {}'.format(i.rstrip(),f2.readline().rstrip()))

else:


   with open(file1,'r') as f1,open(file2,'r') as f2:
       for i in f2.readlines():
           print('{:<100} {}'.format(f1.readline().rstrip(), i.rstrip()))
```

Comment: How do you want to separate the file contents? By number of characters, html tags, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible

```
separator = " "
file1 = open("f1")
file2 = open("f2") 
con1 = file1.readlines()
con2 = file2.readlines()
file1.close()
file2.close()
max_length = max(len(con1), len(con2))
for i in range(max_length):
    print(con1[i].rstrip() + separator + con2[i].rstrip() + "\n")
```

Comment: thanks but problem is all the line are mixing up how can i format to look like a table.

Comment: it do not print more lines for example if file2 has more lines

Comment: I edited the answer. It now uses the length of the longer file for looping trough.